# Fine structure away from the extreme mass ratio limit

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, hydrogen

In kindergarten, all physicists learn how to find the spectrum of bound states of a hydrogen atom by solving the Schrödinger equation with a Coulomb potential. In particular, we get an exact solution for general $m_e$ and $m_p$ by going to the centre-of-mass frame and solving a one-body problem in terms of the reduced mass $\mu = (m_e^{-1}+m_p^{-1})^{-1}$.

Later, we learn how to incorporate relativistic (fine structure) corrections by solving the Dirac equation with an external Coulomb potential. But this is only valid in the extreme mass ratio limit $m_e \ll m_p$, where we can neglect the motion of the proton. As far as I can tell there is a fairly systematic method to compute corrections to this result, such as spin-orbit coupling and radiative corrections, order by order in $\alpha$. I understand that it's also known how to incorporate "recoil" corrections suppressed by factors of $\frac{m_e}{m_p}$. But I can't find anything that computes corrections to the original non-relativistic problem where $m_e$ and $m_p$ are of the same order.

Question: Is it known how to compute the order $\alpha^4 m$ correction to the Coulomb bound states of particles with comparable masses?

A wise physicist once told me that

> A theorist's job is to find all solvable points in theory space and perturb around them.

Has the second part of this maxim been achieved for the lowly hydrogen atom? It strikes me as an unusual situation to have an exact solution but no method (even in principle) for computing perturbative corrections!